# Get all Groups of a user/group recursively

Tags: powershell, active-directory, usergroups

I have some code to get the groups of a user and write them down into an Arraylist, however ît will only find the groups where a user is directly in. It won't find groups deeper then 1 level.

For example: User is member of Group 1, Group 1 is member of Groups 2, etc.
I will only find Group 1. Group 2 won't be written down into my ArrayList.

```
$Groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Server ESX-DC $GroupName

$GroupArrayList = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
foreach ($Group in $Groups)
{
$GroupArrayList.Add($Group.Name) | Out-Null 
}
```

Can someone provide me some help here? Thanks.

Comment: `Get-ADGroupMember` does not work here? Can you not distinguish between groups and users? I would check for groups. If it is a group, check its users.

Comment: [This function](https://github.com/santisq/Get-Hierarchy) is able to recurse on both attributes, `member` and `memberof` and display a hierarchy tree. It's a bit old but for sure works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a recurse parameter so I think you have to write that for your own. How ever, I wrote a scripts for similar tasks. Might that helps.

```
function Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecurse
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.String]$Identity   
    )

    $script:Groups = @()

    function Get-NestedAdGroups
    {
        param
        (
            [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
            [System.String]$Identity   
        )

        $ADGroup = Get-ADGroup -Identity $Identity -Properties MemberOf, Description
        $script:Groups += $ADGroup

        foreach ($Group in $ADGroup.MemberOf)
        {
            if ($script:Groups.DistinguishedName -notcontains $Group)
            {
                Get-NestedAdGroups -Identity $Group
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($Group in (Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity -Properties MemberOf).MemberOf)
    {
        Get-NestedAdGroups -Identity $Group
    }

    return ($script:Groups | Sort-Object -Unique)
}

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembershipRecurse -Identity $SamAccountName
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I found out about [tokenGroups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-tokengroups) [attribute](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/TokenGroups), which is way faster than [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN), so I'm spreading the word:

To get all AD object groups recursively:

```powershell
((Get-ADUser username | Get-ADUser -Properties tokenGroups).tokenGroups | Get-ADGroup).Name
```

Or, if you don't need an ADGroup object, this returns a String instead, but is way faster:

```powershell
(Get-ADUser username | Get-ADUser -Properties tokenGroups).tokenGroups.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
```

It's almost instantaneous in our directory:

```powershell
PS C:\windows\System32> (Get-ADUser -Filter *).Count
86816
PS C:\windows\System32> (Get-ADGroup -filter *).Count
1808
PS C:\windows\System32> (Get-ADComputer -filter *).Count
2666
```

Just for reference, here how much time it takes in this instance:

```powershell
# this returns String objects
1..10 | % {
    Measure-Command {
        (Get-ADUser marcos | Get-ADUser -Properties tokenGroups).tokenGroups.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
    }
} | Measure-Object -Average TotalSeconds | select @{l="Type";e={"String"}},Average

# this returns ADGroup objects
1..10 | % {
    Measure-Command {
        ((Get-ADUser marcossantos | Get-ADUser -Properties tokenGroups).tokenGroups | Get-ADGroup).Name
    }
} | Measure-Object -Average TotalSeconds | select @{l="Type";e={"ADGroup"}},Average

Type       Average
----       -------
String  0.01415692
ADGroup 0.25427236
```

This also returns nested membership of primaryGroup (usually Domain users), which most solutions does not account for.

One downside of this approach is that it does not retrieve distribution groups. If you need that, following query returns just distribution groups, using `LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN` (way faster than retrieving all groups, though):

```powershell
Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter "(&(groupType>=0)(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=myuser,OU=MyUsers,DC=example,DC=com))"
```